# Bootstrap carousel thumbnails indicators

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I copy these code from the bootply sample code for carousel
http://www.bootply.com/79859

But I am having problem with the image thumbnail because it is not working. It is not moving on the specific image while the big image is sliding. I dont' know if I missed a jquery that will support the indicators.

HTML

```
 <!-- thumb navigation carousel -->
<div class="col-md-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs" id="slider-thumbs">
    <!-- thumb navigation carousel items -->
    <ul class="list-inline">
        <li> <a id="carousel-selector-0" class="selected">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=one" class="img-responsive">
      </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a id="carousel-selector-1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=two" class="img-responsive">
      </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a id="carousel-selector-2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=three" class="img-responsive">
      </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a id="carousel-selector-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=four" class="img-responsive">
      </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a id="carousel-selector-4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=five" class="img-responsive">
      </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a id="carousel-selector-5">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=six" class="img-responsive">
      </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a id="carousel-selector-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=seven" class="img-responsive">
      </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a id="carousel-selector-7">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=eight" class="img-responsive">
      </a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- main slider carousel -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="slider">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="carousel-bounding-box">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                <!-- main slider carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=one" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item" data-slide-to="1">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480/888/FFF" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=three" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=four" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="4">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=five" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="5">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=six" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="6">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=seven" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="7">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=eight" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- main slider carousel nav controls --> <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>

                <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--/main slider carousel-->
```

CSS

```
    .selected img {
    opacity:0.5;
    }
```

Jquery

```
 $('#myCarousel').carousel({
 interval: 4000
 });

 // handles the carousel thumbnails
 $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
 var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
 var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
 id = parseInt(id);
 $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
 $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
 $(this).addClass('selected');
 });

// when the carousel slides, auto update
$('#myCarousel').on('slid', function (e) {
var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
id = parseInt(id);
$('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
$('[id^=carousel-selector-'+id+']').addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 3.0

Answer (score 2):

Try this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/xuhP9/)

just remove this class

> hidden-sm  hidden-xs

from

```
<div class="col-md-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs" id="slider-thumbs">
```

it will be work

Comment: Mahmoude Elghandour thank you! this works. I copied your jquery. Finally it works! but I still have a bug, the 2nd thumbnail is active always

Comment: The active thumbnail has class in his <li class="selected"></li>
just make sure that